# Including Entity Metadata and Related Methods Without Dependency in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two Doctrine entities: "Product" and "Highlight". The "Product" entity is part of the "yusrub/catalog" package, while the "Highlight" entity belongs to the "yusrub/highlights" package.

Here is the simplified code for the "Product" entity:

```
/**
 * Class Product
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=
 *     "\Yusrub\Catalog\Domain\Repositories\Doctrine\Product\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product 
{
 /**
     * @var  $highlights
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Yusrub\Highlights\Admin\Domain\Entities\HighLight", inversedBy="products" )
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *   name="highlight_product",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="entity_id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="highlight_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     * )
     */
    protected $highlights;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="associated_highlight_count", options={"default":0})
     */
    protected int $associatedHighlightCount;


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getHighlights()
    {
        return $this->highlights;
    }

    /**
     * @param HighLight $highlight
     * @return \Yusrub\Catalog\Domain\Entities\Product\Product
     */
    public function addHighlight(HighLight $highlight): Product
    {
        if (!$this->highlights->contains($highlight))
        {
            $this->highlights->add($highlight);
            $highlight->addProduct($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param HighLight $highlight
     * @return Product
     */
    public function removeHighlight(HighLight $highlight): Product
    {
        if ($this->highlights->contains($highlight)) {
            $this->highlights->removeElement($highlight);
            $highlight->removeProduct($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAssociatedHighlightCount(): int
    {
        return $this->associatedHighlightCount;
    }
}
```

Currently, the "Product" entity relies on the "Highlight" entity from the "yusrub/highlights" package. However, I want to avoid making the "yusrub/catalog" package dependent on "yusrub/highlights".

Is there a way to include the "Highlight" entity metadata and its related getter and setter methods into the "Product" entity without introducing a package dependency? Alternatively, can I dynamically update the metadata at runtime to achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your help!